Why DO I get Hazed Screen while remote desktop in Linux?

I have a Rasberry pi 4 with rasberry pi os 64 bit. I usually use that as remote desktop for some purpose. I fresh flashed my sd card and installed xdrp,xfce4(desktop env) but whenever I open my browser it shows up as in the picture. Why and how do I fix it?
Forgive for any bad english if any.
Edit of the question with better phrasing is welcome.
